# Creating default object from empty value for message seen

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I want to make the sent message seen when the user clicks on the content but I keep on getting this message.

> Creating default object from empty value for message seen

codes:

```
<div class="chat-body">
    <div class="chat-content override align-left color-text2 seen">
        <input type="hidden" class="id" value="id" />
        <p class="font-size-18"><?php echo ucfirst($msg['subject']);?></p>
        <p><?php echo strip_tags($msg['content']);?></p>
        <time class="chat-time" datetime="2015-06-01T08:30">
        <?php echo date("D, d M, Y | H:i:s", strtotime($msg['created_at'])); ?>
        </time>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','.seen',function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:baseUrl+"/message/seen",
        data:{id:$('.id').val()},
        success: function(response) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(response);
        }
    });
});
```

controller:

```
 public function actionSeen(){
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        $message = MessageTo::find()->where(["id" => $_POST['id']])->one();
        $message->is_seen = 1;
        $message->update();
        echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
    } else {
        echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
    }
}
```

Comment: `value="id"` ??

Comment: i was just testing it out...what should the value be?

Comment: I would say that this query `$message = MessageTo::find()->where(["id" => $_POST['id']])->one();` is failing, therefore `$message` is not an object, therefore `$message->is_seen = 1;` is generating the error

Comment: maybe integer value for your query.

Comment: i think, this is not correct `$message = MessageTo::find()->where(["id" => 'id'])->one();` ?? is it?

Comment: can u please elaborate this..